# How to fix this (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a little application in python, but i have no idea what to do next.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("Welcome to the store!")
price_list = [['apple', 'orange', 'grapefruit', 'bomb', 'gun'], [3, 2, 5, 15, 10]]
inventory = []
print("You can buy the following things")
print(price_list[0][0])
print(price_list[1][0], 'dollars')
print(price_list[0][1])
print(price_list[1][1], 'dollars')
print(price_list[0][2])
print(price_list[1][2], 'dollars')
print(price_list[0][3])
print(price_list[1][3], 'dollars')
print(price_list[0][4])
print(price_list[1][4], 'dollars')
budget = 20
buy = input("What would you like to buy? Type in one of the previous options to buy something You only have 20 dollars to spend though! ")
print("You bought", buy)
if budget >= 0:
    if buy == 'apple':
        print("It cost 3 dollars")
        budget -= 3
        inventory.append('apple')
        print("Your inventory is below")
        print(inventory)
    if buy == 'orange':
        print("It cost 2 dollars")
        budget -= 2
        inventory.append('orange')
        print("Your inventory is below")
        print(inventory)
    if buy == 'grapefruit':
        print("It cost 5 dollars")
        budget -= 5
        inventory.append('grapefruit')
        print("Your inventory is below")
        print(inventory)
    if buy == 'bomb':
        print("It cost 15 dollars")
        budget -= 15
        inventory.append('bomb')
        print("Your inventory is below")
        print(inventory)
    if buy == 'gun':
        print("It cost 10 dollars")
        budget -= 10
        inventory.append('gun')
        print("Your inventory is below")
        print(inventory)
```

I want to make it so i can add one thing, then be able to add another thing until i have reahed my budget, but if i use a while statement, it just keeps adding the thing i buy! help please!

Comment: Is this homework? I'm sorry if it isn't but right now it has the *smell of homework about it*...

Comment: Oh, I'm going to delete my answer until I know if it was homework - or else it would be a bit too easy.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee - upvote for that...you should provide him a hint though! :) I retagged as homework, as it probably is, and even if not, it's of that caliber.

Comment: I am happy to help, but if it's homework I won't say "here's the rewritten code that works", which is how my answer currently is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `if budget >= 0` to `while budget >= 0` is the right idea, you just have to move the request for user input into the while loop as well. That way it will ask for input, check it against the items in the shop, then if `budget >= 0` it will do it again, starting with requesting more input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("Welcome to the store!")

setup_price_list() #pseudocode

budget = 20

while budget >= 0:
    buy = input("What would you like to buy?")
    if buy == 'apple':
        print("It cost 3 dollars")
        budget -= 3
        inventory.append('apple')
        print("Your inventory is below")
        print(inventory)

    #the rest of the if statements

    print("You bought", buy)
    print("Your inventory is below")
    print(inventory)
```

Once you have got that working, I suggest you take a look at the Python Data Structure called a dictionary. It can make code like this much simpler, for example:

```
print("Welcome to the store!")
price_list = {'apple':3, 'orange':2, 'grapefruit':5, 'bomb':15, 'gun':10}
print("You can buy:")
for key in price_list:
    item = key
    price = price_list[key]
    print(item, price)

budget = 20
while budget > 0:
    buy = raw_input("What do you want to buy?")
    price = price_list[buy] #You will get an error if you give it a key it doesn't have
    budget -= price
    print("You bought: ", buy)
    print("It costed: $", price)
```

Oh and you may want to add in a check to see whether you actually have enough money left to buy the item before you buy it, else you can still buy anything as long as you aren't in debt, I'll leave that to you to figure out :)

Comment: There is a bug in your examples which is that the user can buy something without having enough budget to pay for it. You need an 'if' statement to check that they have enough budget for the item.

Comment: To quote: "Oh and you may want to add in a check to see whether you actually have enough money left to buy the item before you buy it, else you can still buy anything as long as you aren't in debt, I'll leave that to you to figure out :)"
Wouldn't want to make it too easy for him now...